# Electrified water from power lines

Tags: electricity

Isn't it water is a good conductor of electricity? How come you don't get shock standing understand a power line when it rains. Or specifically. Supposed the rain is continuous (or a building has leaked water from the tank), and it touches the power line hot wire.. can you get a shock if there is continuous path of water between you and the power line?

Comment: There is still a lot of air even when it rains.  If water was pouring down the electricity would go up to the spout as well as down to the ground and it could be very dangerous.

Comment: Have a look of what power lines do to prevent rain induced shorts, at the end here https://www.scienceabc.com/innovation/why-dont-power-lines-and-towers-short-circuit-during-rains.html

Comment: it seems that the main danger is for the insulator breakage with the column holding the line, not direct to ground. This is avoided by the cup shape of the insulators.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to [this discussion](https://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=425822), at worse the air is 0.2133% water in a hard storm. That's **a lot** of room for air, which is a great electrical insulator. From this, you can see why it's safe to stay under high-power lines when it's raining.

If there were a direct water connection between you and the line, it would be very dangerous indeed !

Comment: How about when bathing.. and the heater tank is connect to hot wire.. and there is continuous water flowing from the tank to the shower and to your body.. would you get a shock? Has this ever occurred before?

Comment: Actually, the heater tank is NOT connected to the hot wire - you would get a shock even when washing your hands. Instead, it goes through a heat exchanger, which has electrical insulation built-in. In short, no electrical wire is connected to any water flow as this is very dangerous.

Comment: I mean if the multipoint heater unit is defective

Comment: I believe you would

Comment: How many percent of water are there in a shower bath flow to your head? Assuming the shower valve is just a hole?